# What is the use of joincolumn and joinTable In hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

what is the main difference between join column and mapped by while using bi-directional mapping .And In the unidirectional mapping what is the use of referenced column inside the join column.

Comment: Have you read the Hibernate documentation, or even the javadoc? What don't you understand?

Comment: I read that document,I am not understanding that If I use mapped by in bi-directional mapping I need to save the parent referrers  each time to child.But for join column there no need to save the parent reference to the child. we can save directly the parent and child directly as like many to one.

Comment: That's how it is. In a bidirectional association, there is an owner side and an inverse side. The owner side is the the side without the mappedBy. And JPA care only about the owner side. So if you modify the inverse side only, the change won't be persisted. It's your responsibility to modify the owner side or, preferrably in most situations, both side, so that the object graph is coherent.

Comment: In bidirectional mapping If Use join column instead of mapped by that's not need to take responsibility to modify the changes.Am I write?

Comment: It's not one or the other. One side has to define the mapping (using JoinColumn for example), and the other side has to use the mappedBy attribute. It's ALWAYS your responsibility to modify the owner side.

Comment: what will happen if I use Both the side as @joincolumn.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49800/discussion-between-user3214269-and-jb-nizet)